# Redirect to subdomain with all path and params after domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

How can I redirect user from one page to the same page, but in subdomain?

> http://test.com
>       to
>       http://subdomain.test.com
>
> http://test.com/page/page2/123
>        to
>       http://subdomain.test.com/page/page2/123
>
> https://test.com/catalog?r=44&color=red
>       to
>       https://subdomain.test.com/catalog?r=44&color=red

So I want redirect and save all what present after `subdomain.test.com` in my example. How can I do it?

```
public function test($request)
    {
        $subdomain = Market::first()->subdomain;
        $domain = $this->get_domain($request);
        $protocol = $this->get_request_protocol($request);

        $to = $protocol . '://' . $subdomain . '.' . $domain; // all path and params?

        return Redirect::to($to);

    }

    private function get_domain($request)
    {
        $parts = explode('.', $request->getHost());
        $i = count($parts)-1;

        return implode('.', [$parts[$i-1], $parts[$i]]);
    }

    private function get_request_protocol($request)
    {
        if ($request->secure()) {
            return 'https';
        }

        return 'http';
    }
```

Comment: What you have try so far?

Comment: Its  possible using .htaccess, Have you tried?

Comment: @drp my subdomain is dynamic. And I need to redirect only when user whant to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
private function get_back_path($url, $domain, $subdomain)
{
    $parts = parse_url($url);

    $url = $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $subdomain . '.' . $domain;
    if (isset($parts['path'])) {
        $url .= $parts['path'];
    }
    if (isset($parts['query'])) {
        $url .= '?' . $parts['query'];
    }
    if (isset($parts['fragment'])) {
        $url .= $parts['fragment'];
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect()->away() like redirect()->away('http://example.com?id=2);

Comment: but how can I get path to redirect?